# 自分 How to know what it means?

Tags: pronouns, ambiguity, reflexives

自分 can mean myself and yourself but, how do you know when the speaker is referring to him/herself or to you? As in, how could you know when the speaker is saying "myself" instead of "yourself" (to the listener)?

Comment: For what it's worth, it does sometimes cost me some centiseconds to figure out who is the 自分 that my friends from Osaka utter.

Comment: Context is key.

Comment: an affirmative sentence…myself 
an interrogative sentence…yourself 
an imperative sentence…yourself 
narcissist's talk…myself

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the verb it's used with.

Examples:

> 自分で**やります** - I will do it myself
>
> 自分で**やってください** - Please do it yourself